# Repeater-like qbs item

Tags: qbs

I am looking for a way to instantiate several qbs items whose quantity and properties are based on some product properties, something like:

```
Repeater {
    model: ["module1", "module2", "module3"]
    delegate: Depends { name: model[index] }
}
```

Problem I'm trying to solve is creating a product with a weak dependence on every other product in the project: to process outputs of dependees which are built, but to never force a product to be built

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such item. The Depends item's productTypes property might do what you need: http://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qbs-1.11/qml-qbslanguageitems-depends.html#productTypes-prop

Comment: can such dependencies be filtered?